What are intercepts in 3D geometry?
I encountered a question which asked for a line which makes equal intercepts with all three axes. How can a line possibly intersect all three axes?
This even made me question if $y = x$ (in 2D) can be considered to have equal intercepts since they both are zero, but according to the equation of line with intercepts, i.e. $x/a + y/b = 1$, we definitely don't get $y=x$.
P.S.: the line which made equal intercepts with all three axes has direction ratios $(1,1,1)$.

Can you provide the original question statement? On the face of it I'd agree that it's indeed not a sensible proposition. (By contrast the problem of finding lines make equal angles with the three axes is well-defined, with the line in the direction $(1,1,1)$ being the most obvious example.)

Find the equation of a line which passes through the point (2,3,4) and which has equal intercepts on the axes.

yes i agree that a line with direction ratios 1,1,1 do make equal angles with the axis. so do i take it that here equal intercepts mean equal angles?

I have a feeling that the question has a typo. It should be "plane" instead of "line".

@Amogh I wondered if it was something like that. But the intersection of a line with, say, the $z=0$ plane would be a point $(x,y,0)$. So if that "point" is the intercept, then it's not at all evident what it means for the intercepts to be equal.

@Semiclassical I meant that a plane passes through $(2,3,4)$, and that intercepts the 3 axes at particular distances from the origin.

@Amogh I see what you mean, and agree that that's the simplest resolution.

A line has three intercepts if it goes through the origin in $\mathbb R^3$. Note that ${(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3: y=x}$ is a plane.

How about the line parameterized as $(x(t), y(t), z(t)) = (t, t, t)$? Its $x$-, $y$-, and $z$-intercepts are all $0$.

@Amogh Thanks for clarifying the question

@JohnDouma Can you elaborate further as a line passing through origin does have 3 intercepts but then why are the direction ratios specified to be (1,1,1) according to the answer when any line passing through origin is acceptable.

@GauriNegi That is one example. Perhaps the question just wanted one example. You should post the original question word for word. It isn't clear from your post whether you are talking about a line or a plane. For example, the solution of the equation $y=x$ in $\mathbb R^3$ describes a plane, not a line.

@JohnDoumaFind the equation of a line which passes through the point (2,3,4) and which has equal intercepts on the axes. this is the question. and for the y=x part, that i was talking about 2D. They both are separate question. sorry if it confused you, it's my first time here.

I think there's not much to be said here. The question is badly formulated. If I could address whoever wrote that question I would point out the bad formulation and ask for clarification.

@GauriNegi You want a line that goes through the origin and $(2,3,4)$. That should be straightforward.

@JohnDouma Yeah though answer doesn't match but vector equation of two points is the most logical and correct approach. Thanks.

@LeeMosher Haha true!
